# Getting Error (Microsoft Web Deploy v3 or higher is recommended.. )while using the build arguments in TFS build definition

Tags: visual-studio-2013, tfsbuild, powershell-3.0

Created a build definition using TFS 2013 to run a scheduled build.
And using SetupSiteForPublish.ps1(see below) in post-build script process to deploy the site on iis on a remote server.

I am referring following 2 articles:

[Article1](http://chriskadel.com/2013/03/using-tfs-to-build-and-deploy-during-the-build-process-with-ms-deploy/)
[Article2](http://www.iis.net/learn/publish/using-web-deploy/powershell-scripts-for-automating-web-deploy-setup)

Now When i use /P:CreatePackageOnPublish=True /P:DeployOnBuild=True

in MSBuild Arguments, getting following error message:

> C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v12.0\Web\Microsoft.Web.Publishing.targets
>   (3739): Package/Publish task
>   Microsoft.Web.Publishing.Tasks.IsCleanMSDeployPackageNeeded failed to
>   load Web Deploy assemblies. Microsoft Web Deploy is not correctly
>   installed on this machine. Microsoft Web Deploy v3 or higher is
>   recommended.

```
param(
    [parameter(Mandatory = $false)]
    $siteName,

    [parameter(Mandatory = $false)]
    $sitePhysicalPath,

    [parameter(Mandatory = $false)]
    $siteAppPoolName,

    [parameter(Mandatory = $false)]
    [int]$sitePort,

    [parameter(Mandatory = $false)]
    $deploymentUserName,

    [parameter(Mandatory = $false)]
    $deploymentUserPassword,

    [parameter(Mandatory = $false)]
    $managedRunTimeVersion, 

    [parameter(Mandatory = $false)]
    $publishSettingSavePath,

    [parameter(Mandatory = $false)]
    $publishSettingFileName
)

##Import-LocalizedData -BindingVariable Resources -FileName Resources.psd1

# ==================================


 #constants
 $SCRIPTERROR = 0
 $WARNING = 1
 $INFO = 2
 $logfile = ".\HostingLog-$(get-date -format MMddyyHHmmss).log"

$template = @"
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<publishData>
  <publishProfile
    publishUrl=""
    msdeploySite=""
    destinationAppUrl=""
    mySQLDBConnectionString=""
    SQLServerDBConnectionString=""
    profileName="Default Settings"
    publishMethod="MSDeploy"
    userName=""
    userPWD=""
    savePWD="True"
    />
</publishData>
"@

#the order is important. Check for apppool name first. Its possible that
#the user gave just a sitename to set permissions. In this case leave apppool emtpy.
#else give a default name to the apppool.
if(!$siteAppPoolName)

{
    if(!$siteName)
    {
        $siteAppPoolName = "AvailabilityServiceAgent"
    }
}
else    
{
    $siteAppPoolName = $siteAppPoolName.Trim()
}

#now the sitename check. If its empty give it a default name
if(!$siteName)
{
    $siteName = "AvailabilityServiceAgent"
}
else    
{
    $siteName = $siteName.Trim()
}

if(!$sitePhysicalPath)
{
    $sitePhysicalPath= $ENV:TF_BUILD_DROPLOCATION+"\_PublishedWebsites\AvailabilityServiceHost"
}
else
{
    $sitePhysicalPath = $sitePhysicalPath.Trim()
}

#global variable. Because we need to return two values from MWA from one function. [REF] has bugs. Hence global
$global:sitePath = $sitePhysicalPath
$global:publishURL = $null

# this function does logging
function write-log([int]$type, [string]$info){

    $message = $info -f $args
    $logMessage = get-date -format HH:mm:ss

    Switch($type){
        $SCRIPTERROR{
            $logMessage = $logMessage + "`t" + $Resources.Error + "`t" +  $message
            write-host -foregroundcolor white -backgroundcolor red $logMessage
        }
        $WARNING{
            $logMessage = $logMessage + "`t" + $Resources.Warning + "`t" +  $message
            write-host -foregroundcolor black -backgroundcolor yellow $logMessage
        }
        default{
            $logMessage = $logMessage + "`t" + $Resources.Info + "`t" +  $message
            write-host -foregroundcolor black -backgroundcolor green  $logMessage
        }
    }

    $logMessage >> $logfile
}


function GetPublishSettingSavePath()
{
    if(!$publishSettingFileName)
    {
        $publishSettingFileName = "WDeploy.PublishSettings"
    }

    if(!$publishSettingSavePath)
    {
        $publishSettingSavePath = [System.Environment]::GetFolderPath("Desktop")
    }

    if((test-path $publishSettingSavePath) -eq $false)
    {
        write-log $SCRIPTERROR $Resources.FailedToAccessScriptsFolder $publishSettingSavePath
        return $null
    }

    return Join-Path $publishSettingSavePath $publishSettingFileName
}

# returns false if OS is not server SKU
 function NotServerOS
 {
    $sku = $((gwmi win32_operatingsystem).OperatingSystemSKU)
    $server_skus = @(7,8,9,10,12,13,14,15,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25)

    return ($server_skus -notcontains $sku)
 }

 # gives a user access to an IIS site's scope
 function GrantAccessToSiteScope($username, $websiteName)
{
    trap [Exception]
    {
        write-log $SCRIPTERROR $Resources.FailedToGrantUserAccessToSite $username $websiteName
        return $false
    }

    foreach($mInfo in [Microsoft.Web.Management.Server.ManagementAuthorization]::GetAuthorizedUsers($websiteName, $false, 0,[int]::MaxValue))
    {
        if($mInfo.Name -eq $username)
        {
            write-log $INFO $Resources.UserHasAccessToSite $username $websiteName
            return $true
        }
    }

    [Microsoft.Web.Management.Server.ManagementAuthorization]::Grant($username, $websiteName, $FALSE) | out-null
    write-log $INFO $Resources.GrantedUserAccessToSite $username $websiteName
    return $true
 }

 # gives a user permissions to a file on disk 
 function GrantPermissionsOnDisk($username, $type, $options)
 {
    trap [Exception]
    {
        write-log $SCRIPTERROR $Resources.NotGrantedPermissions $type $username $global:sitePath
    }

    $acl = (Get-Item $global:sitePath).GetAccessControl("Access")
    $accessrule = New-Object system.security.AccessControl.FileSystemAccessRule($username, $type, $options, "None", "Allow")
    $acl.AddAccessRule($accessrule)
    set-acl -aclobject $acl $global:sitePath
    write-log $INFO $Resources.GrantedPermissions $type $username $global:sitePath
}

 function AddUser($username, $password)
 {
    if(-not (CheckLocalUserExists($username) -eq $true))
    {
        $comp = [adsi] "WinNT://$env:computername,computer" 
        $user = $comp.Create("User", $username)   
        $user.SetPassword($password)
        $user.SetInfo()
        write-log $INFO $Resources.CreatedUser $username
    }
 }

 function CheckLocalUserExists($username)
 {
    $objComputer = [ADSI]("WinNT://$env:computername")
    $colUsers = ($objComputer.psbase.children | Where-Object {$_.psBase.schemaClassName -eq "User"} | Select-Object -expand Name)

    $blnFound = $colUsers -contains $username

    if ($blnFound){
        return $true
    }
    else{
        return $false
    }
 }

 function CheckIfUserIsAdmin($username)
 {
    $computer = [ADSI]("WinNT://$env:computername,computer")  
    $group = $computer.psbase.children.find("Administrators") 

    $colMembers = $group.psbase.invoke("Members") | %{$_.GetType().InvokeMember("Name",'GetProperty',$null,$_,$null)} 

    $bIsMember = $colMembers -contains $username
    if($bIsMember)
    {
        return $true
    }
    else
    {
        return $false
    }
 }

 function CreateLocalUser($username, $password, $isAdmin)
 {
    AddUser $username $password

    if($isAdmin)
    {
        if(-not(CheckIfUserIsAdmin($username) -eq $true))
        {
            $group = [ADSI]"WinNT://$env:computername/Administrators,group"
            $group.add("WinNT://$env:computername/$username")
            write-log $INFO $Resources.AddedUserAsAdmin $username
        }
        else
        {
            write-log $INFO $Resources.IsAdmin $username
        }
    }

    return $true
 }

 function Initialize
 {
    trap [Exception]
    {
        write-log $SCRIPTERROR $Resources.CheckIIS7Installed
        break
    }

    $inetsrvPath = ${env:windir} + "\system32\inetsrv\"

    [System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadFrom( $inetsrvPath + "Microsoft.Web.Administration.dll" ) > $null
    [System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadFrom( $inetsrvPath + "Microsoft.Web.Management.dll" )   > $null 
 }  

 function GetPublicHostname()
{
    $ipProperties = [System.Net.NetworkInformation.IPGlobalProperties]::GetIPGlobalProperties()
    if($ipProperties.DomainName -eq "")
    {
        return $ipProperties.HostName
    }
    else
    {
        return "{0}.{1}" -f $ipProperties.HostName, $ipProperties.DomainName
    }
}

function GenerateStrongPassword()
{
   [System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("System.Web") > $null
   return [System.Web.Security.Membership]::GeneratePassword(12,4)
}

function GetPublishURLFromBindingInfo($bindingInfo, $protocol, $hostname)
{
    $port = 80
    trap [Exception]
    {
        #return defaults        
        return "http://$hostname"
    }

    if(($bindingInfo -match "(.*):(\d*):([^:]*)$") -and
        ($Matches.Count -eq 4 ))
    {
        $port = $Matches[2]
        $header = $Matches[3]
        $ipaddress = $Matches[1]
        if($header)
        {
            $hostname = $header
        }
        elseif(($ipaddress) -AND (-not($ipaddress -eq "*")))
        {
            $bracketsArray = @('[',']')
            $hostname  = $ipaddress.Trim($bracketsArray)
        }

        if(-not($port -eq 80))
        {
            $hostname = $hostname + ":" + $port
        }
    }

    return $protocol + "://" + $hostname
}


function GetUnusedPortForSiteBinding()
{
    [int[]] $portArray = $null
    $serverManager = (New-Object Microsoft.Web.Administration.ServerManager) 
    foreach($site in $serverManager.Sites)
    {
        foreach($binding in $site.Bindings)
        {
            if($binding.IsIPPortHostBinding)
            {
                if($binding.Protocol -match "https?")
                {
                    if(($binding.BindingInformation -match "(.*):(\d*):([^:]*)$") -and
                    ($Matches.Count -eq 4 ))
                    {
                        $portArray = $portArray + $Matches[2]
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    if(-not($portArray -eq $null))
    {
        $testPortArray = 8081..8200
        foreach($port in $testPortArray)
        {
            if($portArray -notcontains $port)
            {
                return $port
            }
        }
    }

    return 8081 #default
}

function CreateSite($name, $appPoolName, $port, $dotnetVersion)
{
    trap [Exception]
    {
        write-log $SCRIPTERROR $Resources.SiteCreationFailed
        return $false
    }

    $hostname = GetPublicHostName
    $global:publishURL = "http://$hostname"
    if(-not($port -eq 80))
    {
        $global:publishURL = $global:publishURL + ":" + $port
    }

    $configHasChanges = $false
    $serverManager = (New-Object Microsoft.Web.Administration.ServerManager) 

    #appPool might be empty. WHen the user gave just a site name to 
    #set the permissions on. As long as the sitename is not empty
    if($appPoolName)
    {
        $appPool = $serverManager.ApplicationPools[$appPoolName]
        if ($appPool -eq $null)
        {
            $appPool = $serverManager.ApplicationPools.Add($appPoolName)
            $appPool.Enable32BitAppOnWin64 = $true

            if( ($dotnetVersion) -and 
            (CheckVersionWithinAllowedRange $dotnetVersion) )
            {
                $appPool.ManagedRuntimeVersion = $dotnetVersion
            }
            $configHasChanges = $true
            write-log $INFO $Resources.AppPoolCreated $appPoolName
        }
        else
        {
            write-log $WARNING $Resources.AppPoolExists $appPoolName
        }
    }

    $newSite = $serverManager.Sites[$name]
    if ($newSite -eq $null)
    {
        $newSite = $serverManager.Sites.Add($name,$global:sitePath, $port)
        $newSite.Applications[0].ApplicationPoolName = $appPool.Name
        if((test-path $global:sitePath) -eq $false)
        {
            [System.IO.Directory]::CreateDirectory($global:sitePath)
        }
        else
        {
            write-log $WARNING $Resources.SiteVirtualDirectoryExists $global:sitePath
        }

        $newSite.ServerAutoStart = $true
        $configHasChanges = $true
        write-log $INFO $Resources.SiteCreated $name
    }
    else
    {
        #get virtual directory and siteport
        $global:sitePath = [System.Environment]::ExpandEnvironmentVariables($newSite.Applications["/"].VirtualDirectories["/"].PhysicalPath)

        foreach($binding in $newSite.Bindings)
        {
            if($binding.IsIPPortHostBinding)
            {
                if($binding.Protocol -match "https?")
                {
                    $global:publishURL = GetPublishURLFromBindingInfo $binding.BindingInformation $binding.Protocol $hostname
                }
            }
        }

        if($appPoolName)
        {
            if (-not($newSite.Applications[0].ApplicationPoolName -eq $appPool.Name ))
            {
                $newSite.Applications[0].ApplicationPoolName = $appPool.Name
                write-log $INFO $Resources.SiteAppPoolUpdated $name $appPoolName
            }
            else
            {           
                write-log $INFO $Resources.SiteExists $name $appPoolName
            }
        }
        else
        {
            write-log $INFO $Resources.SiteExists $name $newSite.Applications[0].ApplicationPoolName
        }
    }

    if ($configHasChanges)
    {
        $serverManager.CommitChanges()
    }   

    return $true
}

function CheckUserViaLogon($username, $password)
 {

 $signature = @'
    [DllImport("advapi32.dll")]
    public static extern int LogonUser(
        string lpszUserName,
        string lpszDomain,
        string lpszPassword,
        int dwLogonType,
        int dwLogonProvider,
        ref IntPtr phToken);
'@ 

    $type = Add-Type -MemberDefinition $signature  -Name Win32Utils -Namespace LogOnUser  -PassThru

    [IntPtr]$token = [IntPtr]::Zero

    $value = $type::LogOnUser($username, $env:computername, $password, 2, 0, [ref] $token)

    if($value -eq 0)
    {
        return $false
    }

    return $true
 }

function CheckUsernamePasswordCombination($user, $password)
 {
    if(($user) -AND ($password))
    {
        if(CheckLocalUserExists($user) -eq $true)
        {
            if(CheckUserViaLogon $user $password)
            {
                return $true
            }
            else
            {
                write-Log $SCRIPTERROR $Resources.FailedToValidateUserWithSpecifiedPassword $user
                return $false
            }
        }       
    }

    return $true
 }

 function CreateProfileXml([string]$nameofSite, [string]$username, $password, [string]$hostname, $pathToSaveFile)
{
    trap [Exception]
    {
        write-log $SCRIPTERROR $Resources.FailedToWritePublishSettingsFile $pathToSaveFile
        return
    }

    $xml = New-Object xml

    if(Test-Path $pathToSaveFile)
    {
        $xml.Load($pathToSaveFile)
    }
    else
    {
        $xml.LoadXml($template)
    }

    $newProfile = (@($xml.publishData.publishProfile)[0])
    $newProfile.publishUrl = $hostname
    $newProfile.msdeploySite = $nameofSite

    $newProfile.destinationAppUrl = $global:publishURL.ToString()
    $newProfile.userName = $username

    if(-not ($password -eq $null))
    {
        $newProfile.userPWD = $password.ToString()
    }
    else
    {
        write-log $WARNING $Resources.NoPasswordForExistingUserForPublish
    }

    $xml.Save($pathToSaveFile)

    write-log $INFO $Resources.SavingPublishXmlToPath $pathToSaveFile
}

function CheckVersionWithinAllowedRange($managedVersion)
{
    trap [Exception]
    {
        return $false
    }

    $KeyPath = "HKLM:\Software\Microsoft\.NETFramework"
    $key = Get-ItemProperty -path $KeyPath
    $path = $key.InstallRoot
    $files = [System.IO.Directory]::GetFiles($path, "mscorlib.dll", [System.IO.SearchOption]::AllDirectories)
    foreach($file in $files)
    {
        if($file -match "\\(v\d\.\d).\d*\\")
        {
            if($Matches[1] -eq $managedVersion)
            {
                return $true
            }
        }
    }
    return $false
}


#================= Main Script =================

 if(NotServerOS)
 {
    write-log $SCRIPTERROR $Resources.NotServerOS
    break
 }

Initialize
if(CheckUsernamePasswordCombination $deploymentUserName $deploymentUserPassword)
{
    if(!$sitePort)
    {
        $sitePort = GetUnusedPortForSiteBinding 
    }
    if(CreateSite $siteName $siteAppPoolName $sitePort $managedRunTimeVersion)
    {       
        if(!$deploymentUserName)
        {
            $idx = $siteName.IndexOf(' ')
            if( ($idx -gt 0) -or ($siteName.Length -gt 16))
            {
                $deploymentUserName = "WDeployuser"
            }
            else
            {
                $deploymentUserName = $siteName + "user"
            }
        }

        if( (CheckLocalUserExists($deploymentUserName) -eq $true))
        {
            $deploymentUserPassword = $null
        }
        else
        {
            if(!$deploymentUserPassword)
            {
                $deploymentUserPassword = GenerateStrongPassword
            }
        }


        if(CreateLocalUser $deploymentUserName $deploymentUserPassword $false)
        {
            GrantPermissionsOnDisk $deploymentUserName "FullControl" "ContainerInherit,ObjectInherit"

            if(GrantAccessToSiteScope ($env:computername + "\" + $deploymentUserName) $siteName)
            {
                $hostname = GetPublicHostName
                $savePath = GetPublishSettingSavePath
                if($savePath)
                {
                    CreateProfileXml $siteName $deploymentUserName $deploymentUserPassword $hostname $savePath
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
Write-Host “Post-build script succeeded!”
```

Comment: Apparently [Web Deploy](http://www.microsoft.com/download/details.aspx?id=39277) isn't installed.

Comment: Ansgar Wiechers thanks for the response.
I have checked Web Deploy 3.5 is installed. I also tried re-installing it. But this has not solved the problem.

Do i need to modify something on MS build arguments?

Comment: Did you create a [delegation in IIS](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/automating-deployment-with-microsoft-web-deploy)?

Comment: Connect to the TFS build agent with the credentials used for the build service and manually run the SetupSiteForPublish.ps1 script.

Comment: @ds 19, manually running the SetupSiteForPublish.ps1 script on server is working, its creating site and app pool in IIS. But not working when trying to call the same script in Post build script process through TFS build

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers checked the article [delegation in IIS](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/automating-deployment-with-microsoft-web-deploy), but this does not provides the solution, all settings for management service delegation and management service are according to the article